# GopherJS and js/dom: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, gopherjs

I'm not sure what's going on here, but I'm trying to load some GopherJS code using the `js/dom` library. Right now I call the routes and listen to the server and then load the scripts. Is this wrong?

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "app/controller"
    "app/script"
)

func main() {
    controller.Setup()
    script.LoadAll()
}
```

script.go:

```
package script

import (
    //"github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js"
    "honnef.co/go/js/dom"
)

func LoadAll() {
    d := dom.GetWindow().Document()

    toggle, slide, navbar, app := d.GetElementsByClassName("lv-navbar-expand")[0].(*dom.HTMLDivElement), d.GetElementsByClassName("lv-slive-nav")[0].(*dom.HTMLDivElement), d.GetElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].(*dom.HTMLDivElement), d.GetElementByID("app").(*dom.HTMLDivElement)

    toggle.AddEventListener("click", false, func(e dom.Event) {
        e.CurrentTarget().Class().Toggle("nav-expand-active")

        slide.Class().Toggle("lv-slide-nav-open")
        navbar.Class().Toggle("lv-slide-nav-is-open")
        app.Class().Toggle("lv-slide-nav-is-open")
    })
}
```

But when I load the website it prints this into the console:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
$goroutine @ ..js:1498
$runScheduled @ ..js:1518
$schedule @ ..js:1534
$go @ ..js:1510
(anonymous) @ ..js:195352
(anonymous) @ ..js:195355
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's impossible to answer the question with the current amount of detail. You'll need to do some debugging, which, unfortunately, is a bit harder in GopherJS than in standard Go. There's no reason to think `script.LoadAll()` is a problem--it should return immediately, has no blocking code, and doesn't launch goroutines. But you haven't included `controller.Setup()`, so we have no way to know if it might be problematic. It's also possible that it's not the problem, either.

Comment: You need to find which goroutines are blocking each other, which begins by finding where goroutines are spawned, and possibly adding some debug output (this could be as simple as 'fmt.Println()` calls.